# In PostgreSQL, how to combine a column from one table with a random value from a second table?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select, random

I am building a test dataset that associates various people with families, and all individual people have a unique ID, and each family (which has multiple people) has a unique ID.

I have created 2 tables, each with people in them that have unique "peopleID" values. The first table has unique "familyID" values. So:

The first table ("people1") looks like this:

person_ID | family_ID | first_name | last_name | date_of_birth | address

*1         | 1         | John       | Smith     | 01-01-1901    | 123 Anywhere St

2         | 2         | Jane       | Jones     | 03-01-1982    | 312 Anyplace Ave

6         | 3         | Harold     | Viking    | 06-30-1973    | 283 Northman Rd*

And the second table (people2) looks like this:

person_ID | family_ID | first_name | last_name | date_of_birth | address

*3         | NULL      | Richard    | Hawkins   | 04-20-2003    | NULL

4         | NULL      | Juliet     | Jordan    | 03-02-2005    | NULL*

And I want to add the rows from people2 to people1, each with a RANDOM familyID from people1, so the end result looks something like this:

person_ID | family_ID | first_name | last_name | date_of_birth | address

*1         | 1         | John       | Smith     | 01-01-1901    | 123 Anywhere St

2         | 2         | Jane       | Jones     | 03-01-1982    | 312 Anyplace Ave

6         | 3         | Harold     | Viking    | 06-30-1973    | 283 Northman Rd

3         | 2         | Richard    | Hawkins   | 04-20-2003    | NULL

4         | 3         | Juliet     | Jordan    | 03-02-2005    | NULL*

---

One way I thought of to do this would be to build a reference table from the second table, like so:

`SELECT person_ID,
  (select family_ID from people1 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1) as family_ID
from people2;`

But that returns a single random entry from "people1" for every row in "people2." How could I force it to return a DIFFERENT random value for every row? A cursor that iterates through each row in "people2" and selects a different familyID value from "people1," perhaps? How would that be written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a temporary table which will associate a subsequent number to every `family_id`:

   ```
   create temporary table family_id_no( no serial primary key, family_id int);
   insert into family_id_no(family_id) 
     select distinct family_id from people1;
   ```

   Associate random `family_id` by choosing random `no`:

   ```
   select person_id, family_id_no.family_id,
     first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, address
   from people2
   left join family_id_no
     using no=trunc(random()*(select max(no) from family_id_no))+1;
   ```

*Untested*

Comment: Good call. I actually ended up there just about when you posted. That allows the tables to be joined. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server formula for generating any random integer in a range is:

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(b-a)+a)
```

where **a** is the smallest and **b** is the largest number in the range.

(However, I believe RANDOM() might be the function for Postgresql, not RAND())

So if your people1.family_ID column is an INT column and there are no missing values in the range (the example you gave works since it has 1,2,3), you could try replacing **a** with `MIN(family_ID)` and **b** with `MAX(family_ID)`

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/rand.php